# Why is the server adding a double forward slash when I did not code it to?

Tags: php

I am trying to load the header file in the home class using a loader. *This works on the local server and shows the whole web page*.

After uploading the codes on to the server, the codes throws a fatal error

> Fatal error: Uncaught LogicException: The template "common/Header"
>   could not be found at "App/View/template//common/Header.tpl"

Looking at the error above, I notice that there is a double forward '//'

```
"App/View/template//common/Header.tpl"
```

I did not add this to the loader code. This is what is in my loader

```
$file = APP_DIR . 'Controllers/' . str_replace("\\", '/', $path_to_controller) . ".php";
$relative_controller = 'Controllers' . preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $path_to_controller);
```

Why is the web server adding a double forward slash on its own?

Comment: You show us code which works with Controllers or php-file. But error happens with template/tpl.

Comment: It's wrongly formatted path, but usually there is no problem with `//` in path/url.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `$path_to_controller` starts with `/`. In that case you can simply remove the forward slash before it:

`$file = APP_DIR . 'Controllers' . str_replace("\\", '/', $path_to_controller) . ".php";`